# how to set environment variable in linux using perl script

Tags: perl

how do you set environment variable in linux using perl script.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
system ('export TEST_ENV=TEST123');
```

not working. Please help

Comment: Every process has its own set of environment variables. A child processes gets a copy of the set of its parent process, but it really is a copy, any change is not reflected in the parent process. You cannot change environment variables of one process from another process. That is why this doesn't work.

Comment: Your script **is working**, and correctly set the environment variable for the _new_ shell, started by the `system` function. Its lifetime is finished when the shell is finished. (immediatelly after the `export`).

Comment: `system` spawns a new child process, changing the environment in this child process is futile. You can only change the environment of the running perl process by using `%ENV` (e.g. `$ENV{'TEST_ENV'}='TEST123';`. You **cannot** change the environment of the shell that started the perl process. This can only happen from within the shell itself.

Comment: thanks for all of your answers but I managed to do a resolution for this now, and still using a perl script :D

Answer (score 1):

use `%ENV` for that:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$ENV{'TEST_ENV'} = 'TEST123';
```

Comment: tried your code but it's not working also.

Comment: Where do you plan to use the environment variable? Inside the Perl script?

Comment: Where do you try to use the variable?

Comment: @Quentin not inside the perl script. I need to add a new system environment variable on a linux machine using a perl script.

Comment: @nairb why you have to use perl? why not a shell script?